# How do I center this "navbar"?

Tags: html, css

I added this options to make a small navbar, but I can't make the content to be centered. So it looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Gvw.png)

What do I need to change so it displays all the options in the centre?

Here is the code:
I don't know if the snippet will look exactly like the picture I attached, but I think the problem will still be noticeable

```css
body{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0;
}
/*Esto es el logo*/
#parte1{
    background-color: #da291c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}
#menu{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;

}
/*Esta es la blowjob de los equipos*/
#parte3{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 25% 0px 25%;
    height: 150px;
    font-family: Arial;
    

}

#logo{
    
    background-color:  #da291c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

#parte1-samsung{
    background-color: #da291c;
}
#parte2-samsung{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 25px;
    display: inline-flex;

}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-self: center;

}

 nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #d02e10;
    background-color: #d02e10;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    
 }

a{
    text-decoration: none; 


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Caracteristicas Claro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <center>
        <div id="parte1" class="container">
            <a href="https://tiendaclaro.pe" title="Tienda Claro"  > <img src="icons/LogoClaro.png" 
                alt="Claro" 
                height="50"
                id="logo" 


                 >
            
            </a>

        </div>

    </center>
    </header>

    <nav id="menu" class="nav">

            <ul>

        <li><a  href="Web Claro.html" title="Volver al Inicio"  id="reinicio" >

            INICIO

        </a>


        <li><a  href="equipos-samsung.html" title="Ver equipos Samsung" target="_blank" id="resamsung" >

            SAMSUNG

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-apple.html" title="Ver equipos Apple" target="_blank" id="reapple" >

            APPLE

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-huawei.html" title="Ver equipos Huawei" target="_blank" id="rehuawei" >

            HUAWEI

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-xiaomi.html" title="Ver equipos Xiaomi" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            XIAOMI

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-motorola.html" title="Ver equipos Motorola" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            MOTOROLA

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-honor.html" title="Ver equipos Honor" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            HONOR

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-Oppo.html" title="Ver equipos Oppo" target="_blank" id="reoppo" >

            OPPO

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-realme.html" title="Ver equipos Realme" target="_blank" id="rerealme" >

            REALME

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-vivo.html" title="Ver equipos Vivo" target="_blank" id="revivo" >

            VIVO

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-zte.html" title="Ver equipos ZTE" target="_blank" id="rezte" >

            ZTE

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-coolpad.html" title="Ver equipos Coolpad" target="_blank" id="recoolpad" >

            COOLPAD


        </a>

        </ul>


    </nav>

    <!-- Aqui iniciaria toda la estructura de los equipos -->
    <div id="parte3">
        <h2>Equipos</h2>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   #menu{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Arial;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
 }
```

does this fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put text-align: center on your #menu nav element.

Also, you should avoid using the center tag that surrounds the #parte1 div. That is long deprecated. All you need to do is put text-align: center on your #parte1 div, and it will center it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex position to the `<ul>` tag with `justify-content : center` property.

You can also add the property `flex-wrap : wrap` for the responsive design.

```css
body{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0;
}
/*Esto es el logo*/
#parte1{
    background-color: #da291c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}
#menu{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
/*Esta es la blowjob de los equipos*/
#parte3{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 25% 0px 25%;
    height: 150px;
    font-family: Arial;
    

}

#logo{
    
    background-color:  #da291c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

#parte1-samsung{
    background-color: #da291c;
}
#parte2-samsung{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 25px;
    display: inline-flex;

}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-self: center;

}

 nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #d02e10;
    background-color: #d02e10;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    
 }

a{
    text-decoration: none; 


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Caracteristicas Claro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <center>
        <div id="parte1" class="container">
            <a href="https://tiendaclaro.pe" title="Tienda Claro"  > <img src="icons/LogoClaro.png" 
                alt="Claro" 
                height="50"
                id="logo" 


                 >
            
            </a>

        </div>

    </center>
    </header>

    <nav id="menu" class="nav">

            <ul>

        <li><a  href="Web Claro.html" title="Volver al Inicio"  id="reinicio" >

            INICIO

        </a>


        <li><a  href="equipos-samsung.html" title="Ver equipos Samsung" target="_blank" id="resamsung" >

            SAMSUNG

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-apple.html" title="Ver equipos Apple" target="_blank" id="reapple" >

            APPLE

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-huawei.html" title="Ver equipos Huawei" target="_blank" id="rehuawei" >

            HUAWEI

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-xiaomi.html" title="Ver equipos Xiaomi" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            XIAOMI

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-motorola.html" title="Ver equipos Motorola" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            MOTOROLA

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-honor.html" title="Ver equipos Honor" target="_blank" id="rexiaomi" >

            HONOR

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-Oppo.html" title="Ver equipos Oppo" target="_blank" id="reoppo" >

            OPPO

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-realme.html" title="Ver equipos Realme" target="_blank" id="rerealme" >

            REALME

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-vivo.html" title="Ver equipos Vivo" target="_blank" id="revivo" >

            VIVO

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-zte.html" title="Ver equipos ZTE" target="_blank" id="rezte" >

            ZTE

        </a>

        <li><a  href="equipos-coolpad.html" title="Ver equipos Coolpad" target="_blank" id="recoolpad" >

            COOLPAD


        </a>

        </ul>


    </nav>

    <!-- Aqui iniciaria toda la estructura de los equipos -->
    <div id="parte3">
        <h2>Equipos</h2>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```